# Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand not returning anything in "Output" field when executing from Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to invoke a powershell script on to a Virtual Machine and retrieve the output of the script. I'm using the **Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand** cmdlet to invoke the script on the VM as shown below.

```
$ValidationResult = Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -VMName $VM.Name -CommandId "RunPowerShellScript" -ScriptPath $ValidationScript
```

When I execute the above cmdlet from a regular powershell terminal, I get the output as expected. However, whenever I'm putting this statement inside an automation runbook, I get null in almost all the fields as shown below

[image]

I don't see anything specific to this in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-5.7.0) as well. Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**Update:**
In the script, I'm logging the output using Write-Output cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Apologies for the delayed response. I was using this in a runbook of type **Powershell *Workflow***. Many of the PowerShell cmdlets behave differently when executed in workflows.

So in this case, what was happening is the Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand was executing correctly but the response was only the TYPE of the response and not the actual response object. Hence I  was unable to see any values in the response's properties.

In order to make this work, I had to wrap the cmdlet call within an `InlineScript {}` block.

```
$ValidationResult = InlineScript {
    $result = Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $USING:VM.ResourceGroupName -VMName $USING:VM.Name -CommandId "RunPowerShellScript" -ScriptPath $USING:ValidationScript

    $result.SubStatuses[0].Message
}
```

The result is returned to $ValidationResult variable.

More detailed post is given here: https://amoghnatu.net/2018/04/15/get-output-of-script-executed-as-part-of-set-azurermvmcustomscriptexecution-cmdlet/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add the object name on last line of your script or use the Write-Output command. Otherwise it will not output anything.

The following lines both write an object to the output stream.

- Write-Output –InputObject $ValidationResult
- $ValidationResult

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages

Hope this helps

Comment: I have this already in the script. Thanks for pointing it out though. Let me clarify my question.

Comment: Please post the script entirely, not the command line, but Runbook script

Comment: Unfortunately, I would not be able to post the runbook here but let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I need to see the last line of it

Comment: Write-Output $log

Comment: This is the last line in the script that I'm running on the VM

Comment: Then its not $ValidationResult, so dont expect it to give same result as the line you have provided intially :). How do you compose the $log variable, what does it contain when you run the runbook from, lets say, Powershell console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168814/discussion-between-amogh-natu-and-mareks-zirdzins).

Comment: Sure, although +1 to my answer also would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: I'm having (almost) exactly the same issue. Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand used to print the output but nothing anymore, just returns empty. And I'm just running the command on Powershell straight, not runbook.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely due to a reported bug in the AzureRM modules starting with version 5.7.0 / April 2018. Rolling back to version 5.6.0 / March 2018 is reported to fix it. Issue log: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5982